# Assigning range to array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get excel data into an array in VBA, so I do the following:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C28:R29")
```

As soon as I run this, I get a type mismatch error 13.
I thought the problem was because the 1st row (2 rows in total) represents a string (header) and the 2nd row represents numbers, so I tried to only get one row like this:

```
Arr= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C28:R28")
```

To no avail, I still get the same problem.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Regards
Crouz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just add `.Value` (I discovered that trick not so long ago and I'm already fan! :) )

```
Arr= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C28:R28").Value2
```

Comment: I have never understood this.
`Arr=Range("C28:R28")` will work but `Arr= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C28:R28")` does not.  Don't both variations return a `Range` object?  Any thoughts?

Comment: A lot of but no useful I'm afraid, I never used the `Array=Range` so I don't really now but it might have to do with the data type (numerical, text, ...) that is in your range. But I can't help you more that this!

Comment: When putting ranges in arrays use `Value2` rather than `Value`. Charles Williams explains this well at his blog.

Comment: Ok, jhere is the link : https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/
And to sum up, `.Value` convert some of your data to keep dates and such, and cut your number with a 4 digits accuracy, and `.Value2` is faster because it doesn't convert anything and so it can't threaten your data integrity!