# Explicit and implicit use of ActiveSheet when assigning a range to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

When considering @Crouzilles question: [Assigning range to array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607270/assigning-range-to-array-in-vba) I realized that it mattered whether or not `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` was explicitly used to define a range.  For example:

```
Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant

arr1 = Range("A1:B2")
arr2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")               'Type mismatch
```

I had assumed that both right hand sides would return a `Range` object and this would be cast into an array of variants; however, the second line generates a type mismatch error:

```
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
```

To ensure that both statements did indeed return an array I checked `TypeName()`:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Range("A1:B2"))                            'Range
Debug.Print TypeName(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")) 'Range
```

I also checked the `Range("A1:B1").Worksheet.Name` property to ensure that `Range("A1:B2")` was indeed a reference to the `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.references

I then tried to assign `Range().Value` to the arrays both variations, which executed correctly:

```
arr1 = Range("A1:B2").Value
arr2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Value          'No error
```

This makes sense as `.Value` converts a `Range` object to an array of variants....the same type as `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Range("A1:B2").Value)                      'Variant()
Debug.Print TypeName(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Value)   'Variant()
```

To add to my confusion, explicitly assigning both variations to `Range` references allowed both arrays to be assigned:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1:B2")
Set rng2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")

arr1 = rng1
arr2 = rng2                                                     'No error
```

Can anyone explain why a `Range` object referenced by `Range("A1:B2")` can be implicitly cast to an array of variants whilst `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")` cannot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to do with the binding, and the use of default properties. `Activesheet` returns an Object, not a `Worksheet` so everything after that is late bound, whereas `Range(...)` is actually shorthand for `Application.Range` so it's early bound. If you declare a worksheet variable and assign ActiveSheet to it, the code will also work:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
arr2 = ws.Range("A1:B2") ' works
```

Declaring the variables as `Variant` rather than `Variant()` will also work.

Moral of the story: **always specify the property you mean!**

From the VBA language spec:

***5.6.2.3 Default Member Recursion Limits***

Evaluation of an object whose default Property Get or default function returns another object can lead to a recursive evaluation process if the returned object has a further default member.  Recursion through this chain of default members may be implicit if evaluating to a simple data value and each default member has an empty parameter list, or explicit if index expressions are specified that specifically parameterize each default member.

An implementation may define limits on when such a recursive default member evaluation is valid.  The limits may depend on factors such as the depth of the recursion, implicit vs. explicit specification of empty argument lists, whether members return specific classes vs. returning Object or Variant, whether the default members are functions vs. Property Gets, and whether the expression occurs on the lefthand-side of an assignment. 
The implementation may determine such an evaluation to be invalid  statically or may raise error 9 (Subscript out of range) or 13 (Type mismatch) during evaluation at runtime

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Is there a way to show that on object is late bound programatically?  I can see it would be obvious with `Dim obj As Object` but intuitively I'd expect `ActiveWorksheet` to return a `Worksheet` and indeed `TypeName(ActiveWorksheet)` would suggest this as well.

Comment: But it's not `ActiveWorksheet`, it's `ActiveSheet` and that sheet could be a Chart sheet (or a macro sheet even) - that's why it returns an `Object`, not a `Worksheet`. The Object Browser will show the return type.

Comment: @stucharo - The best hint that something was bound late is if you type a '.' after it and don't get a member list in the Intellesense.