# Excel VBA Macro combing through 80,000+ rows of data taking 23 hours to complete

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new here and just got into Excel VBA coding.

I'm having an issue with a snippet of code I ran. I have multiple columns to show the status of a loan payment.

- Column 1 shows the numerical value of the year (i.e. Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc.).
- Column 4 shows the ID number of the contract.
- Column 5 shows the status of the loan payment (CURRENT = currently paid, 1-23 = 1 to 23 days delinquent, 24-59 = 24 to 59 days delinquent, etc.).
- Column 6 shows the amount of $$$'s owed.

My goal:

1. Have the code use the ID and search for ID numbers in the list below it.
2. Then, if there is a match in ID, it checks if the months are sequential (i.e. if the month of the ID in the current row matches the ID in the loop row and if the month is one above the current row, so if it finds a match for the ID in January, it will look for the same ID in February).
3. Then, it will check Column 5 to see if the account transitioned into delinquency from the previous month (i.e. if the Delinquency was CURRENT in January and then went into the 1-23 days delinquent bucket in February).
4. Finally, if all of these are true (the ID's match up, the month is sequential, and the delinquency shifted) it will drop the amount owed into a Column related to the delinquency shift (Columns 7-9).

My issue: I am running this with a statusbar update to check if it's running. It's going at about 1 iteration of i per second. At 83,110 rows of data, I calculate this to take about 23 hours. HOLY SMOKES! Is there any way to expedite this?

Here's my code:

```
Sub DecipherDPD()

Dim i As Long, CurrentRow As Long, IDSearch As Long
Dim RawData As Worksheet
Dim CollectionsWB As Workbook

Set CollectionsWB = ThisWorkbook

Set RawData = CollectionsWB.Worksheets("RAW DATA")

CurrentRow = 2

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For i = CurrentRow To 83111 Step 1
    For IDSearch = i + 1 To 83111 Step 1
        If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 4) = RawData.Cells(i, 4) Then
            If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 1).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 1).Value + 1 Then
                If RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "CURRENT" Then
                    If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "1-23" Then
                        RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 7) = RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 1).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 1).Value + 1 Then
                If RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "1-23" Then
                    If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "24-59" Then
                        RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 8) = RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 1).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 1).Value + 1 Then
                If RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "24-59" Then
                    If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "60-90" Then
                        RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 9) = RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 1).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 1).Value + 1 Then
                If RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "60-90" Then
                    If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "90+" Then
                        RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 9) = RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next IDSearch
Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
-Joe

Comment: Do you know if it freezes and crashes completely? It's possible (probable) that with such a large set, it does freeze but the code still is running.  Also, try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to the top (then turn to `True` and `XlCalculationAutomatic` at the very end.

Comment: Immediately after the first for statement, add Application.Statusbar = i so you can see what it is doing. At the end add application.Statusbar = False to clear the statusbar.

Comment: Thanks Batman, err...Bruce. I have ScreenUpdating set to False and I just added in the xlCalculation. I cannot use CTRL+ALT+PAUSE or CTRL+PAUSE to pause it or CTRL+ALT+BREAK or CTRL+BREAK to break it. I'm not sure if that means it's completely not responding. I let it run for 5 hours yesterday, and it was still running. Not sure if that's demonstrative of it freezing/crashing, but I would think that it could crunch through the numbers in 5 hours...

Comment: @jkpieterse, I added in the StatusBar and set it to i. It hits 10 and then stops.

Comment: @jkpieterse, I tried it again and it got to 11 and then stopped...

Comment: **A)** Until you get it working, comment out `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` - that just makes it more difficult to figure out what's going on. It's fantastic to have _once your code works correctly_. **B)** Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see what it's hanging on? Since it seems to hang on the 11th iteration, use F5 to quickly get through the first 10 loops, then F8 to go line by line until you see where it stops responding.

Comment: Ok! It seems to be running! Thank you everyone. However... New issue: It's running at about one line per second. For 83110 lines, it will take roughly 23 hours to process. Any ideas on how to expedite this?

Comment: It will be many times quicker if you [read all the data into an array first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607270/assigning-range-to-array-in-vba), and do array operations, then write back to the sheet.

Comment: @Wolfie I'll check it out. I haven't used Arrays yet, so this is new territory for me. I guess I have some reading ahead of me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

I just noticed that you do in fact change the column index for the write operations. Still, take into account the below advice on using arrays and separate your logic back out and it should work!

---

As suggested, you should look at reading to an array to speed up operations. To make that conversion a lot easier (and possibly speed up your code anyway), try using `And` and `Or` to combine the logical statements and reduce the number of `If`s. This version is **nearly** equivalent, and ideas could be used in your code:

```
For i = CurrentRow To 83111 Step 1
    For IDSearch = i + 1 To 83111 Step 1
        If RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 4).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 4).Value And RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 1).Value = RawData.Cells(i, 1).Value + 1 Then
            If     (RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "CURRENT" And RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "1-23") _
                Or (RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "1-23" And RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "24-59") _ 
                Or (RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "24-59" And RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "60-90") _ 
                Or (RawData.Cells(i, 5) = "60-90" And RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 5) = "90+") Then
                    RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 7) = RawData.Cells(IDSearch, 6)
            End If
        End If
    Next IDSearch
Next I
```

Then working with arrays should look something like this:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = RawData.Range("A" & CurrentRow & ":G" & 83111).Value
For i = LBound(arr,1) To UBound(arr,1)
    For IDSearch = i + 1 To UBound(arr,1)
        If arr(IDSearch, 4) = arr(i, 4) And arr(IDSearch, 1) = arr(i, 1) + 1 Then
            If     (arr(i, 5) = "CURRENT" And arr(IDSearch, 5) = "1-23") _
                Or (arr(i, 5) = "1-23" And arr(IDSearch, 5) = "24-59") _ 
                Or (arr(i, 5) = "24-59" And arr(IDSearch, 5) = "60-90") _ 
                Or (arr(i, 5) = "60-90" And arr(IDSearch, 5) = "90+") Then
                    arr(IDSearch, 7) = arr(IDSearch, 6)
            End If
        End If
    Next IDSearch
Next i
RawData.Range("A" & CurrentRow & ":G" & 83111).Value = arr
```

There is no need for `ScreenUpdating` fiddles as the screen only updates right at the end anyway, with the single read and single write operations being the thing which makes this method quick.

Comment: Way way waaaaaaaay faster. Arrays are clearly some magical, untiring steed of incredible haste, that whisked through my data at a speed that would make The Flash envious. I have a lot to learn, but thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction and helping me work through this!

Comment: It's because you're not reading and writing from/to the Excel document constantly :) consider marking this as accepted if it answers your issue :)

Comment: The inner "IDSearch" loop is totally pointless and makes the procedure exponentially slower. Replace that loop with "IDSearch = i + 1" (still putting it just above the If statement) and it does the exact same thing in <1 second.

Comment: Except, @DanielMcCracken, that it currently allows for conditional matches when `IDSearch` is not equal to `i + 1`, so you've defined different logic there?

Comment: Oh I was assuming that the data was already sorted by LoanID and period, so that the "match" (if it existed) would always be in the next row. But I just realized that's not in the original post. My bad! Either way, that'd be the way to do it: sort the source data first, then read it into the array, and you can avoid the inner loop. Sorting barely adds any time to the procedure compared to adding a few billion additional loops.

Comment: It may not be practical to re-sort the data I guess, or you could sort it *once it's in the array* if that was useful. Depends on the data really :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to approach this. One is similar to Wolfie's (reads data into an array + loops through), another one uses regular worksheet formulas.

First, you'll want to turn your data into a Table (go to Insert -> Table) and give it/your columns descriptive names (you can name a table after creating it by clicking the "Design" tab and looking at the top left, there's a little place to enter a name). That by itself will make your code (and any formulas on the source data sheet) a lot more readable + easier to maintain. With a table, you won't have to worry about modifying your macro if you add/delete/move columns in your source data.

(It looks like your data is already basically in a tabular format, so creating a table shouldn't present an issue. But if it does, just copy the source data onto another sheet and make the table there.)

Then you're going to want to sort your table by Loan ID and period. Working with sorted data is often *significantly* faster than working with unsorted data,
 definitely in this case and also in [many other cases](http://www.exceluser.com/blog/727/excels-fastest-lookup-methods-the-tested-results.html). Here's what your table should look like at this point:

[image: img]

Then you've got a couple of alternatives. One starts the same as Wolfie's by reading the data into an array, but because the data is sorted, any "match" you find will always be 1 row away, and you avoid looping through the data multiple times. In my testing, this version averaged ~1.5 seconds with a 100k row table.

The other works similarly, but uses worksheet formulas. It's a bit slower (averaged ~5 seconds with a 100k row table) but I find it a bit easier to work with if you ever need to make modifications.

Either way, here's what it'll look like afterwards:

[image: img]

```
Sub calculateLoanStatus()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startTimeSetup As Double, endTimeSetup As Double
    Dim startTimeArr As Double, endTimeArr As Double
    Dim startTimeForm As Double, endTimeForm As Double

    'Sort data in table by loan ID and period
    startTimeSetup = Timer
    Dim loanTbl As ListObject
    Set loanTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").ListObjects("LoanTable")
    Call sortColumn(loanTbl, "Period", xlAscending)
    Call sortColumn(loanTbl, "Loan ID", xlAscending)
    endTimeSetup = Timer - startTimeSetup

    'Option 1: Use helper method to copy data into array + paste it back to the table
    'Faster, but slightly more difficult to maintain
    startTimeArr = Timer
    Call versionOne(loanTbl)
    endTimeArr = Timer - startTimeArr + endTimeSetup

    'Option 2: Use helper method to create formulas + copy the results to each column
    'Slower, but slightly easier to maintain
    startTimeForm = Timer
    Call versionTwo(loanTbl, "Current to 1-23", "Current", "1 to 23")
    Call versionTwo(loanTbl, "1-23 to 24-59", "1 to 23", "24 to 59")
    Call versionTwo(loanTbl, "24-59 to 60-90", "24 to 59", "60 to 90")
    Call versionTwo(loanTbl, "60-90 to 90+", "60 to 90", "90+")
    With loanTbl.DataBodyRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    endTimeForm = Timer - startTimeForm + endTimeSetup

    'End
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Array version: " & endTimeArr & vbNewLine & "Formula version: " & endTimeForm

End Sub
Sub versionOne(tbl As ListObject)
'Read data from a sorted table (tbl) into an array and calculate values

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim startCol As Long
    Dim periodCol As Long, loanIDCol As Long, statusCol As Long, amountCol As Long
    Dim resultCol1 As Long, resultCol2 As Long, resultCol3 As Long, resultCol4 As Long

    startCol = tbl.ListColumns(1).Range.Column
    periodCol = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("Period").Range.Column - 1
    loanIDCol = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("Loan ID").Range.Column - 1
    statusCol = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("Status").Range.Column - 1
    amountCol = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("Amount Owed").Range.Column - 1
    resultCol1 = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("Current to 1-23").Range.Column - 1
    resultCol2 = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("1-23 To 24-59").Range.Column - 1
    resultCol3 = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("24-59 To 60-90").Range.Column - 1
    resultCol4 = startCol + tbl.ListColumns("60-90 To 90+").Range.Column - 1

    arr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
        nextRow = i + 1
        arr(nextRow, resultCol1) = ""
        arr(nextRow, resultCol2) = ""
        arr(nextRow, resultCol3) = ""
        arr(nextRow, resultCol4) = ""
        If arr(nextRow, loanIDCol) = arr(i, loanIDCol) And arr(nextRow, periodCol) = arr(i, periodCol) + 1 Then
            If (arr(i, statusCol) = "Current" And arr(nextRow, statusCol) = "1 to 23") Then
                arr(nextRow, resultCol1) = arr(nextRow, amountCol)
            ElseIf (arr(i, statusCol) = "1 to 23" And arr(nextRow, statusCol) = "24 to 59") Then
                arr(nextRow, resultCol2) = arr(nextRow, amountCol)
            ElseIf (arr(i, statusCol) = "24 to 59" And arr(nextRow, statusCol) = "60 to 90") Then
                arr(nextRow, resultCol3) = arr(nextRow, amountCol)
            ElseIf (arr(i, statusCol) = "60 to 90" And arr(nextRow, statusCol) = "90+") Then
                arr(nextRow, resultCol4) = arr(nextRow, amountCol)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    tbl.DataBodyRange.Value = arr

End Sub
Sub versionTwo(tbl As ListObject, shiftCol As String, oldStatus As String, newStatus As String)
'Add formula to a column (shiftCol) in a table (tbl)
'Use loan account's status in the prior (oldStatus) and current (newStatus) months to whether to add value
'If desired, copy the results of the formula in place (copyText)

    Dim refCol As Long
    Dim periodDist As Long
    Dim loanIDDist As Long
    Dim statusDist As Long
    Dim formulaText As String

    'Determine the distance between your reference column and each value column
    refCol = tbl.ListColumns(shiftCol).Range.Column
    periodDist = tbl.ListColumns("Period").Range.Column - refCol
    loanIDDist = tbl.ListColumns("Loan ID").Range.Column - refCol
    statusDist = tbl.ListColumns("Status").Range.Column - refCol

    'Make formula and add it to the column
    formulaText = "=IF(AND(R[-1]C[" & periodDist & "]=[@Period]-1,R[-1]C[" & loanIDDist & "]=[@[Loan ID]]," & _
                  "R[-1]C[" & statusDist & "]=""" & oldStatus & """,[@Status]=""" & newStatus & """),[@[Amount Owed]],"""")"

    tbl.ListColumns(shiftCol).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = formulaText

End Sub
Sub sortColumn(tbl As ListObject, toSort As String, sOrder As Variant)
'Sorts column (toSort) in a table (tbl) in a given order (sOrder)

    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=tbl.ListColumns(toSort).Range, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=sOrder, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I'm excited to give it a try and compare it. I agree that Tables are the way to go, so I should start incorporating them in my Macro files as well. Thanks again!